# How to properly texture a quad in opengl

Tags: c, opengl

I am reasonably new to OpenGL, and upon getting comfortable with rendering of basic shapes, I decide I wanted to learn how to add textures, and a quick Google search gave me the SOIL libraries. I decided to start out simple by applying a a texture to a quad that filled the window. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>

#define WIDTH 0x320
#define HEIGHT 0x258
#define INIT_X 0
#define INIT_Y 0

GLuint texture;

GLuint glInitTexture(char* filename)
{
    FILE* f = NULL;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
        if(f == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot load file %s!", filename);
            exit(1);
        }
    GLuint t = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filename, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    return t;
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    texture = glInitTexture("image.png");
}

void drawImage(GLuint file,
    float x,
    float y,
    float w,
    float h,
    float angle)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, file);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x, y, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(x, y + h, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x + w, y, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)//courtesy of http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/preparing-the-window-for-a-reshape/
{
    if(h == 0) h = 1;
    float ratio = w * 1.0 / h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gluPerspective(45.0, ratio, 0.1, 1000.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void render()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    drawImage(texture, 0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 0.0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(INIT_X, INIT_Y);
    glutCreateWindow("Applying Textures");

    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutIdleFunc(render);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);

    init();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

However when I load compile and run the program, the only thing I get is a window with a white background. I should also note that the file "image.png" does exist and is filled red to contrast with white background for testing purposes. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and/or what I'm missing from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity modelview matrix results in a 'camera' at the origin looking down the -Z axis.

Your `drawImage()` is plopping down a quad that's co-planar with the Z=0 plane.  Which is *behind* the near clipping plane for the identity matrix.

Scoot the camera back a bit so you aren't embedded in the Z=0 plane:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef( 0, 0, -15 );  // this is where the magic happens
```

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

GLuint glInitTexture(char* filename)
{
    GLuint t = 0;

    glGenTextures( 1, &t );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    unsigned char data[] = { 255, 0, 0, 255 };
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
    return t;
}

void drawImage(GLuint file,
    float x,
    float y,
    float w,
    float h,
    float angle)
{
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, file);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x, y, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 2.0); glVertex3f(x, y + h, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(2.0, 2.0); glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(2.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(x + w, y, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}

GLuint texture;
void render()
{
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    const double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    const double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective(45.0, w / h, 0.1, 1000.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0, 0, -15 );

    drawImage(texture, 0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f, 4.0f, 0.0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Applying Textures");
    glutDisplayFunc(render);

    texture = glInitTexture("image.png");

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For rendering a full screen quad, you should always consider using coordinates in the range `[-1,1]` for 2 triangles. No need to setup any modelview or projection matrix at all, just use identity matrices since vertex positions in that range will automatically fit the entire window.

Comment: Thanks a million, but one thing I'm still unclear on: from what I can tell, in this case it seems like the image is only used as a placeholder to bind the texture, however the actual data used when the image is drawn to the screen seems to be given by `unsigned char data[] = { 255, 0, 0, 255 };`. Is there any way that I would be able to draw the data directly from the image for something more obscure, like, say, If i wanted to display a brick wall?

Comment: Just sub in your original `glInitTexture()` function.